# 500 error on production server after model update

Tags: django, database, heroku, django-models, migration

I deployed a new django app on Heroku which worked out fine. However, today I changed my model a little bit (added a new field) and afterwards deleted my development server file db-sqlite3 and the migrations folder in order to reflect the changes in the development database. This worked out fine on the local server but when I pushed this to heroku I get a 500 error when trying to access the model in the django-admin section.

I tried to run some migrations via heroku but I get the following error message:

```
 ! These migrations are in the database but not on disk:
    <joins: 0002_auto__add_field_join_ip_address>
    <joins: 0003_auto__add_unique_join_email>
    <joins: 0004_auto__add_field_join_ref_id>
    <joins: 0005_auto__add_unique_join_email_ref_id>
    <joins: 0006_auto__add_unique_join_ref_id>
    <joins: 0007_auto__del_unique_join_ref_id>
    <joins: 0008_auto__del_unique_join_email__add_unique_join_ref_id>
    <joins: 0009_auto__add_field_join_friend>
 ! I'm not trusting myself; either fix this yourself by fiddling
 ! with the south_migrationhistory table, or pass --delete-ghost-migrations
 ! to South to have it delete ALL of these records (this may not be good).
(lwc) Daniels-MacBook-Pro:src danielrichter$ heroku run python manage.py migrate --delete-ghost-migrations
```

I can see that in my local migrations folder I only have the 0001_initial migration and somehow missing the other but I have no idea how to resolve the issue.

I have seen that others ran into the same error message, but I did not understand the proposed answers, since I am quite new to Django and coding in general. So if there is someone who could give me a hint how to resolve this I would be very thankful!

many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the database thinks you have applied the migrations mentioned in the message, but it can't find the files on disk. Which you confirm. Maybe there was something wrong with your version management and you lost these files? I'd try to see if you can recover the files, then the problem would be over.

If not, it is a bit more difficult. The migrations mentioned have probably already been executed but the files are lost. Also you have made new changes which have not been applied. You should try to get your code state back to the state where the last missing migration was executed. You can then make a new migration file (`python manage.py schemamigration --auto your_app_name`) which can replace the missing migration files. This migration will be called 0002_something (0001 being present and 0002 being the next). After this replacement migration you can have new migrations (0003 and further).

On the server, before updating your version of the code (so you don't already have 0002) execute `python manage.py migrate --delete-ghost-migrations`. This will delete the references to the missing migration. Afterwards you can update your version and get the new 0002 etc migrations.

Call `python manage.py migrate --fake your_app_name 0002`. This will tell the database that the migration was applied, without actually applying anything. This is good because the changes were already applied by the lost migration files.

After this, you can run normal migrations: `python manage.py migrate` and it should be good.

Hope this helps.

Comment: many thanks lucas! The error message is gone, now the only issue I have is that the deployed app throws a 500 error every time I go in the django-admin section and try to access the model that I have changed. However, everything works out fine on the development server, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you put on DEBUG=True, so you can see the actual error? **Edit:** Ah, I see it from the post below. You're missing a field in the database. Did you check in the last migration file that the field is being added to the database?

Answer (score 0):

> and afterwards deleted my development server file db-sqlite3 and the
> migrations folder in order to reflect the changes in the development
> database

This is your issue, you shouldn't delete any migration files, if you make a change in your database, django (or south) will create a new migration file for those changes, then you run the migration command to apply those changes to your database, you have to commit those new migration files and send them to heroku, so the changes will be applied to the remote database too.

The workflow is like this:

1. You have some migration files or the initial one
2. Edit your models by adding/removing fields
3. Create migration file(s), in django (without South):

   `python manage.py makemigrations`
4. Apply those changes to your local database by runnig:

   `heroku run python manage.py migrate`
5. Add those model changes and migration files to your git index
6. Push the changes to heroku and run the migration command:

   `heroku run python manage.py migrate`

Comment: thanks @ahmed, I followed your instructions (however with Django 1.6 `schemamigrations myapp --auto` instead of `makemigrations`), and now I set the debug mode to true on the production server to see what is going on and I see  `ProgrammingError at /
column joins_join.wunschrad does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "joins_join"."id", "joins_join"."email", "joins_join"...` it's clear to me that the field that I added in the model is not there but how the hell can I add it, i did everything from migrate over syncdb, both on heroku and on local server, even checked the models.py file on the server

Comment: when I run `heroku run python manage.py migrate joins` the bash returns `Running migrations for joins:
- Nothing to migrate.
 - Loading initial data for joins.` so there is no real error message from the migration side, locally the app works perfectly but there is some issue on the server, I even created a new heroku app but the same thing is happening ; i was thinking that it might be an issue with the code in git and i have to flush it and re-push it again but it's just a guess

Comment: Do you still have the migration files that you've deleted in your heroku repo? if yes, you can pull them and delete your current local database and add the new migration files (step 5)